# Is it possible to determine the measures of the angles of a right angled triangle not using calculators and tables when the side lengths are given?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

When I studied in class ten, I used to think if the measures of the angles of a right angled triangle could be obtainable without using trigonometric tables or scientific calculators?

It took me a while to formulate the formula. I amazed when the observed values came close to the calculated values and variation in values occurred by 0-0.5.

Formulation:-
If ΔABC is a right angled triangle 
where m∠B=90° and AB=c, BC=a & AC=b units (AB

m∠A= (?×?)÷? (Locked)
m∠C= (?×?)÷? (Locked)

Observation:-

1). 3,4 & 5 units 
36.87°, 53.13° & 90° (Calculator) 
36.5°, 53.5° & 90° (Formula)
Variation =36.87-36.5=0.37

2). 5,12 & 13 units
22.62°, 67.38° & 90° (Calculator)
23°, 67° & 90° (Formula)
Variation=23-22.62=0.38

3). 7,24 & 25 units
16.26°,73.74° & 90° (Calculator)
16.68°, 73.32° & 90° (Formula)
Variation=16.68-16.26=0.42

The numerical approximations to the answers can be obtainable.

Comment: What is your quiestion exactly?

Comment: @Somos For example, If ΔABC is a right angled triangle where m∠B=90° and AB=3 cm BC=4 cm & AC=5 cm, then m∠A=? & m∠C=?

Is it obtainable without using calculators or trigonometric tables?

Comment: Can't we do without using any electronic device? Isn't there any non-trigonometric formula yet?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just draw the triangle you described with a ruler and measure the angles with a protractor.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.  You can do any computation your computer can do if you have enough energy and patience.  People calculated $\pi$ to hundreds of places before the age of calculators and computers.  How much accuracy do you want and how much work are you willing to do?  The small angles are easier.  You can use the Taylor series
$$\arcsin x=x + x^3/6 + (3 x^5)/40 + (5 x^7)/112 + (35 x^9)/1152 + (63 x^{11})/2816 + O(x^{12})$$
For the $7-24-25$ triangle $x=0.08$ so this many terms should get you fifteen places or so.  For the $3-4-5$ the angle is larger and you would probably want to expand around $\frac \pi 4$ or to use the half angle formulas to get a smaller angle